# What would be a best practice workflow for creating python environments with Anaconda?

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, conda

I am trying to set up a standardized workflow for python development for data science. I came across, the popular, Anaconda distribution. But I could not find good documentation on how to setup the workspace.

I created an `environment.yml` file with the following contents in `/workspace/aws-scripts`

```
name: aws-scripts
dependencies:
  - python=3.*
  - boto3
```

When I created the environment,

```
conda env create -f environment.yml -p $PWD
```

the directory structure created is this:

```
.
├── bin
├── conda-meta
├── environment.yml
├── include
├── lib
├── share
└── ssl

6 directories, 1 file
```

Should the git ignore file include all the 6 directories that are created?

The default Anaconda prefix is `~/anaconda3/envs.` When I changed the prefix for just this workspace, I no longer could list this as an environment using

```
conda info --envs
```

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conda environments are used to have isolated setup in terms of Python version and installed libraries. There are **not** the place to put your own source code. So keep them in the default location `~/anaconda3/envs` and do not version control this third party code. Put our own code in the directory `/workspace/aws-scripts` and use version control there. You can always re-create a conda environment by exporting all settings as a yaml file and using this file to create a new conda environment somewhere else.

Comment: Thats for dispelling the misconception I had regarding environments.